# How to receive UDP socket data in SignalR Hub C#

Tags: c#, signalr

I have created a hub in SignalR in my web project. In my hub class I want to receive udp data sent on port no 4001. Please suggest the code to receive data through udp socket. I tried to receive using the code as shown below but it gives error "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted"

**ClockHub.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace RealTimeClock.App_Code
{
    public class ClockHub : Hub
    {
        public void getSocketData()
        {     
       // Here I want to receive udp socket data  on port 4001 

        // my code commented here did not work
            //UdpClient receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(11000); 
            //IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            //Byte[] receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
            //string UDP_Rx_Data= Encoding.ASCII.GetString   rceiveBytes);  



            
            Clients.Caller.setTime(UDP_Rx_Data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: signalr uses websocks, not quite sure what you are trying to do.  If you are trying to receive udp data and send it via signalr, then make a service to handle udp packets and then dispatch it to the hub

Comment: @KeithNicholas  I want to receive here the Count Down Timer generated by a console application. The console application sends count down time via udp socket on 4001. I want to receive that timer here and then push to the web clients.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an intermediary app to receive the UDP packets and then forward them onto the SignalR Hub.

Intermediary App which can be set to auto restart using task Scheduler:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace UdpToSignalR
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static readonly string hubURL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HubURL"];
        private static readonly int listenPort = int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UDPPort"]);

        private static void StartListener(IHubProxy hub)
        {
            UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
            IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);

            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
                    hub.Invoke("getSocketData", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                listener.Close();
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {

            HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(hubURL);
            var hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("ClockHub");
            connection.StateChanged += (state) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"State Changed: {state.NewState}");
            };
            connection.Reconnecting += () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Reconnecting....");
            };
            connection.Closed += () =>
            {
                // If we loose hub connection close the app so that the task scheduler can fire it up again.
                Environment.Exit(0);
            };
            connection.Start().Wait();

            StartListener(hub);

        }
    }
}
```

This code grabs your hub url and UDP Port from the app config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="UDPPort" value="4001"/>
    <add key="HubURL" value="http://localhost:54856/signalr"/>
</appSettings>
```

Your hub code would then be:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace RealTimeClock.App_Code
{
    public class ClockHub : Hub
    {
        public Task getSocketData(string message)
        {     
            Clients.Caller.setTime(message);
        }
    }
}
```